# How to make large quantities of API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I have below code to make API calls

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (id) => {
      try {
        const result = await fetch(
          `http://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/football/nfl/athletes/${id}`
        );
        const body = await result.json();
        setData(body.athlete.college.name);
      }
    };

    // call the async fetchData function
    let length = 50;
    const total = 2902;
    for (let id = 1; id < length; id++) {
      fetchData(id);
    }
  }, []);
```

I need to make in total, 2902 API calls. I could send all at once by changing length value to 2902 but then API calls will fail after certain limit and I will most likely get banned. How can I make 50 API calls at a time until I make total of 2902 API calls? Start from 1 to 50, when all done, do 51-100, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make all the calls at once, as Chrome (for example) will only process 6 async calls at a time anyway

If there's a specific rate limit set by the server you may need to add in a setTimeout, or possibly cache results to prevent repeated calls for the same data - but you'd need to specify what the limits are in your question for a more accurate answer I think

Comment: If I set the length to 2900, it does make all of them and API calls starts failing after about 800 or so... if you get fiddler working let me know please, It doesnt work for me...

Comment: I am thinking of a solution that'd invole setInterval to like 5 seconds and start a new set of API calls every 5 seconds..